# Can i get different programs on the desktop of a virtual desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-desktop

I want one desktop to display my general programs on the desktop background and on the other my games. So that if i want to play a game i just press *Ctrl+Windows+Right Arrow Key* it changes the icons on my desktop to my games instead of Google Chrome etc.

---

- **I thought it was a setting somewhere but i couldn't find it.**
- **Is there any way to achieve this?**
- **Or similar without needing to install a program to get the same result?**

---

> *Possible solutions could be a program changing the* * */desktop folder to*
>   *some other folder location with the programs all set.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is open the desktop switcher (button in the taskbar, if activated), then drag any window to another desktop.

Do note, the Virtual Desktop that comes with Windows 10 is still very basic. You can't automatically make programs go there, so you will have to perform this action every time you start windows. Although it is possible (I haven't tested this) that with the latest version of Windows, where programs relaunch at startup if they were not closed on shutdown, automatically also load in the same virtual desktop.

If you want more flexibility, you will need to download and install other Virtual Desktop software. There are free programs and paid programs out there. I have lots of experience with ActualTools programs so if money is not an issue, I can recommend those. But I've also toyed with Dexpot and VirtuaDesk. The free programs can be a pain to setup though, and their functionality can break for no apparent reason.

Comment: Its not about the programs but the icons on the desktop. [Desktop Icons](https://i.imgur.com/g3OfEi9.png)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no Virtual Desktop manager that can do this.